# having trouble printing /reading a dictionary I created from a csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I need to create a dictionary from a csv file, and although I don't get any errors when running my code, my output comes out blank.
this is how my code looks like:

```
    def make_happy_dict():
        filename = "happiness.csv"
        happy_dict = {}
        with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
            csv_happy = csv.reader(infile)
            infile.readline()
            for line in csv_happy:
              line = line.strip("\n")
              line[0], line[2] = line.split(",")
              happy_dict[line[0]] = line[2]
        print(line[0], line[2])
```

this is very beginner/basic so if you have any suggestions and explanations I would appreciate that so much!
i'm not sure if you need the csv data so let me know if you do and I will update :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  is that ```print(...)``` line supposed to be indented inside the ```for line in csv_happy:```` loop?

Comment: Have you called the function? csv.reader splits each line into rows - a list of values. The first line of the for loop, `line = line.strip("\n")` should fail, because "line" is a list.

Comment: Also your function returns nothing.

Comment: @ewokx yes, when I don't indent it gives me an error, but that could also be due to another factor I may not be seeing.

Comment: @tdelaney ah is there a way to turn that list into columns? I'd like to format it differently than what the output is giving me

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not called this function. If you do, it will fail. `csv.reader` splits the lines for you. You iterate lists that hold the column values for a single row. Had you attempted `line.strip("\n")`, you would have gotten an exception because `line` is a list, not a string. You could pass filename to the function instead of hard-coding it, and return the happy dictionary when done

```
def make_happy_dict(filename):
    happy_dict = {}
    with open(filename, newline="") as infile:
        infile.readline()
        csv_happy = csv.reader(infile)
        for row in csv_happy:
          happy_dict[row[0]] = row[2]
    return happy_dict
    
happiness = make_happy_dict("happiness.csv")
print(happiness)
```

And instead of the for loop, you could create and fill the dictionary in one step

```
def make_happy_dict(filename):
    with open(filename, newline="") as infile:
        infile.readline()
        return {row[0]:row[2] for row in csv.reader(infile)}
```

There are many ways to format the data for output. Perhaps the easiest is to print each item:

```
for country, value in happiness.items():
    print(f"{country} {value}")
```

Or create a single string with multiple lines

```
display = "".join(f"{country} {value}" for country,value in happiness.items()}
```

That's just a couple of the possibilities.

Comment: thank you! is there a function I can use like strip/split to format my data? I want to organize it so the output is, for example, -->         Mexico 2.8473\nuriguay 3.8663\n    etc etc